# PHP headers forced download and then redirect

Tags: php, redirect, download

Right now I have a PHP form that forces a download of a zip.

How can I redirect to another page and also force that download?

Would I use JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do both on the same page : force download the file (using the Content-disposition header) and redirect the user.

One thing you could is use JavaScript to open a new window to the download age when clicking on a link, and then redirect the user to an other page after a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in your download redirect:

```
Header("Location: downloadscript.php?filename");
```

Good luck!